# Position image widget in mega menu

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, menus, sub-menu

I need to add image in mega menu. So I have added image widget in menu. How can I reposition this widget. Currently my menu is showing like this.

[image]

But I need image only in the right side, and sub category `EAR RING` is on left side(below anklet). This is how I am setting the sub menu from admin.

[image]

Comment: Drag and drop the widget to your liking?

Answer (score 0):

I your mega menu, search for alignment option to align the widget. Alternatively, you may need CSS to manually override the positioning. How exactly would you like it to display, maybe I can help?